# ffmpeg mp3 streaming via node js

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, node-streams, fluent-ffmpeg

```
var fs = require('fs');
var child = require('child_process');
var http=require('http')
var input_file = fs.createReadStream('./remo.mp3');
http.createServer(function (req,res) {
var args = ['-ss',120,
'-i', 'remo.mp3',
'-f','mp3',
'pipe:1' // Output on stdout
];
var trans_proc = child.spawn('ffmpeg', args);
res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg'
  });

trans_proc.stdout.pipe(res)
trans_proc.stderr.on('data',function (err) {
console.log(err.toString());
})
}).listen(2000)
```

i am trying to cut the mp3 and streaming to the browser but in browser it showing corrupted file

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell if you're asking about **downloading** a youtube video as an mp3 using node - but this thread popped up on top of google when I was researching just that. So, if not, perhaps it can point you in the right direction or help someone in the future... Mods - sorry if I'm not doing this right.

[Additional StackOverflow Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33725893/how-do-you-use-node-js-to-stream-an-mp4-file-with-ffmpeg)

But I am using the following code to do **download** a youtube vid as mp3 (download youtube vid  / convert to mp3 / download) :

```
module.exports.toMp3 = function(req, res, next){
var id = req.params.id; // extra param from front end
var title = req.params.title; // extra param from front end
var url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + id;
var stream = youtubedl(url); //include youtbedl ... var youtubedl = require('ytdl');

//set response headers
res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + title + '.mp3');
res.setHeader('Content-type', 'audio/mpeg');

//set stream for conversion
var proc = new ffmpeg({source: stream});

//currently have ffmpeg stored directly on the server, and ffmpegLocation is the path to its location... perhaps not ideal, but what I'm currently settled on. And then sending output directly to response.
proc.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegLocation);
proc.withAudioCodec('libmp3lame')
    .toFormat('mp3')
    .output(res)
    .run();
proc.on('end', function() {
    console.log('finished');
});
```

};